# Three.js - How to change selected object material in a buffered geometry?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a bunch of objects in a buffered geometry.

Question:
How can I change a single object's material properties so that all other objects are not affected?

Details:

I can obtain a single selected object (via ray casting technique).
Also I can see that the selected object only has a .material property (not .materials). This .material property happens to be the material for the buffered geometry. So when I change the material property (lets say color) for the selected object, it actually affects ALL objects in the buffered geometry.

I hope this explanation/issue makes sense.

How I obtain the selected object:

```
var intersects = this.Raycaster.intersectObject(this.Mesh);

                if (intersects.length > 0) {
                    this.IntersectObject = intersects[0];
```

How I get the selected object's material:

```
this.IntersectObject.object.material
```

Comment: one mesh has one geometry and one material, if you merged multiple geometries into one they cannot have different materials, maybe you have multiple meshes with the same material reference and that is why all objects are affected

Comment: I have 1 buffered geometry. So I believe this is 1 mesh, right?

Comment: So to work around this "1 mesh, 1 material" restriction, will I be able to change an object's properties, like color, or its opacity, even though it's in a buffered geometry?

Comment: not as easy as if you used multiple meshes, you will probably need to add custom attributes to your geometry and write your own shader material to make use of them(for example opacity is a uniform = bound to material, not to vertex), color i think is already built--in as an attribute and adding "color" attribute and changing values for each vertex of a object should work without  refer to [documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Renderers.WebGL/WebGLProgram)